# What are some formulas involving Dottie number and digamma function?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, digamma-function

Here are two formulas that involve Dottie number and Gamma function:

$\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{d}{\pi} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{d}{\pi} \right) = \frac{\pi}{d}
$

and

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi^2}-\left(\frac{d}{\pi}\right)^2}\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{d}{\pi} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{d}{\pi} \right)=1$

[Source.](https://vixra.org/pdf/1802.0427v1.pdf)

Are there similar formulas involving digamma function?